# Java Generics extends Loop

Tags: java, generics

how can i loop through object which extends from a class?
i give an example:
I have an Abstract class (AbstractDTO) and 2 classes which extends AbstractDTO:

```
public abstract class AbstractDTO
{
    private int id;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
}


public class FirstDTO extends AbstractDTO
{

}

public class SecondDTO extends AbstractDTO
{

}
```

Now i got a method which excpects 2 Collections of objects which extends AbstractDTO.
I want to add all objects of the second list to the first list, if they are not in the first list already.
how can i do this?

i tried the following:

```
public static void summarizeCollection(List<? extends AbstractDTO> firstList, Set<? extends AbstractDTO> secondList)
    {
        for(AbstractDTO second : secondList)
        {
            boolean exists = false;
            for (AbstractDTO first : firstList)
            {
                if (second.getId() == first.getId())
                {
                    exists = true;
                }
            }
            if(!exists)
            {
                firstList.add(second);
            }
        }

    }
```

I got an error in the line " firstList.add(second);" cause my second object is of the type AbstractDTO and not of a class which extends AbstractDTO.

Can someone help me with that?
Thx alot ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler cannot be sure that the elements in `secondList` are of the same type of the elements declared in `firstList`, thus you get a compiler error here:

```
firstList.add(second);
```

This is caused for the definition of the arguments:

```
List<? extends AbstractDTO> firstList, Set<? extends AbstractDTO> secondList
```

If you're sure both `List` and `Set` are of the same type and this type extends `AbstractDTO`, then declare your method like this:

```
public static <T extends AbstractDTO> void summarizeCollection(List<T> firstList, Set<T> secondList)
```

Then, inside the method, change this `for` loop:

```
for(AbstractDTO second : secondList)
```

into

```
for(T second : secondList)
```

And on.

More info:

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/1065197)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler error is there because the compiler cannot guarantee that the wildcard from the `List` is equal to the wildcard from the `Set`.

You can solve this by making the method generic.  You need a type variable to represent the type of the `List`, which must be an `AbstractDTO`, say `T`.  You can make the `Set` a wildcard bounded by `T`, so that a `Set` of any type that is `T` or extends `T` can have its elements added to the `List`.

```
public static <T extends AbstractDTO> void summarizeCollection(
    List<T> firstList, Set<? extends T> secondList)
```

Then both `for` loops' variables should be of type `T`.

```
for(T second : secondList)
```

and

```
    for (T first : firstList)
```

This will allow the call to `add` to compile.